# Anyone Know of Some Desktop Software that Searches an SQL server for a String

Tags: sql-server

I have a database on a server that's running Microsoft SQL. I would like to find a tool that logs into that server, allows me to search to a string, and returns the tables and fields that contain that string. **I"m not a programmer, nor do I know SQL.** I saw someone using free desktop software that does this, but I've come to a Google dead-end. Does anyone know a software product that does this?

I don't think monitoring software is what I'm looking for. I might be wrong, but when I look at those products (RedGate, etc), they seem like overkill.

Comment: Red Gate has a free [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) tool but I think that it's only accessible through Sql Server Management Studio, so that would have to be installed and you'd have to be able to login to the server.

Comment: Do you have access to any tool that has a query builder? That would let you write query without knowing SQL.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I don't have a query builder, but I'm willing to get one. Any suggestions?

Comment: @swasheck Yeah, I saw that, but I can't install things on the server. If I had access, I'd install that and be golden.

Comment: Which tool have you seen? They can usually be installed on any workstation and then connect to the database over the network.

Comment: @Dorje you dont have to run it on the server. you can install ssms on your client machine and then run sql search on ssms on that machine.

Comment: @swasheck Oooooooo! I can do THAT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Download SSMS [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985)

Step 2: Download Red Gate SQL Search [LINK](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

Step 3: Install both

Step 4: Connect to your database server

Step 5: Search!

Comment: is the OP looking for a way to search content of the database or schema/objects of the database? Redgate's tool works for the later.

Comment: Good point of clarification. I guess I took for granted that they were looking for schema/object definitions and not a query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using a script through SSMS the script below will search through user tables for a certain string.  In a system with a lot of tables and columns it will take a long time.  :)

```
set nocount on

declare
    @TableName varchar (100)
    ,@ColumnName varchar (100)
    ,@TableSchema varchar (100)
    ,@min int
    ,@max int
    ,@sql nvarchar (4000)
    ,@string varchar (2000)
    ,@SummaryLevel int

--  search criteria
--      @string fro string to be searched in all relevant fields in all tables
--      @SummaryLevel 0 for detailed results, 1 for search hit count by table
select
    @string = '<the string you want to search for>'
    ,@SummaryLevel = 1

create table #cols (
    colsId int identity (1,1) primary key
    ,TableName varchar (100)
    ,TableSchema varchar (100)
    ,ColumnName varchar (100)
)

create table #results (
    resultsId int identity (1,1) primary key
    ,TableName varchar (100)
    ,ColumnName varchar (100)
    ,ColumnValue varchar (4000)
    ,SummaryLevel int
)

insert into #cols ( TableName, TableSchema, ColumnName )
select
    T.TABLE_NAME
    ,T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,C.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you got truncated or what, but OP may want to know from what you're `SELECT`ing.

Comment: Sorry man, SO won't let me put in the whole script.  The field accepts it but I get a timeout on the save.  I think the back end engine doesn't agree with all my single ticks.  :)  If you're interested in a script to do this I can post it up somewhere, but I got the impression you were looking for a client side application to do this.